# Pandas rolling count frequency of specific value in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, rolling-computation

I want to have a rolling count column that tracks the count of a specific value in a column. I want a rolling count of how many times the horse has finished 1st.

This is an example of what I have

| Horse | Position |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 3 |
| a | 1 |
| b | 3 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 5 |
| c | 2 |
| c | 1 |

This is what I want

| Horse | Position | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 |
| a | 3 | 1 |
| a | 1 | 2 |
| b | 3 | 0 |
| b | 1 | 1 |
| b | 3 | 1 |
| c | 5 | 0 |
| c | 2 | 0 |
| c | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

You can group-by "Horse" and then `.cumsum` over the first places in each group:

```py
df["Count"] = df.groupby("Horse")["Position"].apply(lambda x: x.eq(1).cumsum())
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Horse  Position  Count
0     a         1      1
1     a         3      1
2     a         1      2
3     b         3      0
4     b         1      1
5     b         3      1
6     c         5      0
7     c         2      0
8     c         1      1
```

Comment: Thanks for our help :)

Comment: Would you know how to then add a win percentage column?

Answer (score 0):

First compare `1` and then use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) for avoid `apply` for improve performance:

```
df["Count"] = df["Position"].eq(1).groupby(df["Horse"]).cumsum()
```

Or create helper column:

```
df["Count"] = df.assign(new = df["Position"].eq(1)).groupby("Horse")['new'].cumsum()
```

---

```
print (df)
  Horse  Position  Count
0     a         1      1
1     a         3      1
2     a         1      2
3     b         3      0
4     b         1      1
5     b         3      1
6     c         5      0
7     c         2      0
8     c         1      1
```

EDIT:

```
g = df.assign(new = df["Position"].eq(1)).groupby("Horse")['new']
df["Count"] = g.cumsum()
df['perc'] = g.transform('mean').mul(100)
print (df)
  Horse  Position  Count       perc
0     a         1      1  66.666667
1     a         3      1  66.666667
2     a         1      2  66.666667
3     b         3      0  33.333333
4     b         1      1  33.333333
5     b         3      1  33.333333
6     c         5      0  33.333333
7     c         2      0  33.333333
8     c         1      1  33.333333
```

Comment: Would you know how to then add a win percentage column?

Comment: @Maria - Sure, add `transform` with `mean`, answer was edited.

Comment: The first win perc should be 100 as the horse has run 1 race and won it. The second perc should be 50 then the thrid one should be 66